# Understanding a regular expression in a series extract function in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, expression, extract

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['toy story (1995)', 'the pirates (2014)'])
print(s.str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*',expand = True))
```

with output:

```
     0
0  1995
1  2014
```

I understand that the extract function is pulling the values between the parentheses for both series objects. However I do not understand how. What exactly does `'.*\((.*)\).*'` mean? I think that the asterisks represent wild card characters but beyond that I am quite confused as to what is actually going on with this expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*\(` matches everything up until the first `(`

`\).*` matches everything from `)` until the end

`(.*)` returns everything in between the first two matches

Answer (score 1):

```
.*             Match any number of characters
\(             Match one opening parenthesis
    (.*)       Match any number of characters into the first capturing group
\)             Match a closing parenthesis
.*             Match any number of characters
```

This notation is called a regular expression, and I guess Pandas uses regexes in the `extract` function so you can get more precise data. Things inside capturing groups would be returned.

You can learn more about regexes at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Here's [a test example](https://regex101.com/r/SDLZFY/1) using your regex.